# Htaccess redirect for hundreds URL

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I have old site with hundreds URL that look like that:

> http:www.domain.com/Contact.asp?Pid=344
>
> http:www.domain.com/Contact.asp?Pid=345
>
> http:www.domain.com/Contact.asp?Pid=346

and so on ...

I need to move all of them permanent to 1 single URL :

> http:www.domain.com/contact

I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Contact.asp?Pid=([0-999]+) 

RewriteRule ^http://www.domain.com/contact? [L,R=301]
```

But it doesn't work well.

The old site use `ASP`. The new site build on `Joomla`. The domain will be the domain from old site

Comment: Have you tried without http : //www.domain.com/ ?

Comment: Now i try and it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You're close. You need to use the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable like you did, but the var *doesn't* include the URI-path (the `Contact.asp?`) part. Also, your `RewriteRule` is missing a regex pattern. Try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Pid=([0-999]+) 

RewriteRule ^/?Contact\.asp$ http://www.domain.com/contact? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Almost ...
the issue is like that: I develop the new site inside folder ( www.develop-domain.com/client-name. when I put what you send me with folder path, it jump back to main domain dir and put "?Pid=344" in the end.

Comment: @user1788813 The `?` at the end of the target prevents automatically appending of the query string, when I use these rules in a blank htaccess file, there is no `?Pid=` at the end. If you want this to work under arbitrary directories, remove the `http://www.domain.com/` and use a `RewriteBase /your-directory/`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^Contact.asp?Pid=(\d) /contact? [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the only pages you have on there the contact pages? You could just 301 the entire directory since they are all moving to one URL.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This site have also another pages that i manage to do 301 redirect. The problem is that contact pages. I have hundreds ...